# how to evaluate this triple integral with cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

how to evaluate $\displaystyle \underset{E}\iiint dV$ , if $ E = \{(x,y,z)^T \in 
 \mathbb R^3: x^2z^2 + y^2z^2 \leq1, \frac{1}{2} \leq z \leq 1 \}$;
 the problem is that the $r$ is a function of $z$ instead of the angle $\theta$, so i don't know what to do next.

Comment: I don't know why you consider it important that the " r is a function of z instead of the angle $\theta$".  Volume in cylindrical coordinates is given by $\int \int \int r cos(\theta) drd\theta dz$.  The boundary is $r^2z^2= 1$ so that r runs from 0 to $\frac{1}{z}$.  The volume is given by $\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{1/z}\int_0^{2\pi} r cos(\theta) d\theta dr dz$

Comment: @user247327 thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

cylindrical coordinates:

$x = r \cos t\\
y = r\sin t\\
z = z\\
dx\ dy\ dz = r\ dr\ dz\ dt$

limits

Substituting from above:

$z^2 r^2 \le 1\\
r^2 \le \frac 1{z^2}\\
0\le r\le \frac 1z$

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac 12}^1 \int_0^\frac {1}{z} r\ dr\ dz\ dt$

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The domain of integration is

$$x^2+y^2 \leq z^{-2} \text{ where } z \in [1/2,1].$$

Integrate the circular area elements to obtain

$$\int_{1/2}^{1}\pi\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2 dz.$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: yes，but wht if i parameterize x,y,z？

Comment: @lfc199471 then you can do the substitutions user247327 did in the comments.